# JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove the tags and make the selected text between the tags to upper, don't know how?

```
 var pattern = 'We are <orgcase>liViNg</orgcase> in a <upcase>yellow submarine</upcase>.' 
 var myRegexp = /<upcase>(.*?)<\/upcase>/g;
 var match = "$1";
 var str = pattern.replace(myRegexp, match.toUpperCase());
 console.log(str);
```

Comment: You need an XML/HTML parser

Comment: what is your goal ? are you making some new markup language ?

Comment: Try `var str = pattern.replace(myRegexp, (m, m1) => m1.toUpperCase());` [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6twum5o/). `m1` is corresponding to `(.*?)` first capture group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `replace` with a callback so the matched values can be fed to it and handled.

```
 var str = 'We are <orgcase>liViNg</orgcase> in a <upcase>yellow submarine</upcase>.' 
 var str = str.replace(/<upcase>(.*?)<\/upcase>/g, function($0) { return $0.toUpperCase(); });
 alert(str);
```

As for then removing the tags:

```
str = str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/g, '');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgdxj7at/).

Comment: Your question remains the same, and I've answered it.